# Please help to run the build in IOS Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test, flutter-ios, flutter-ios-build

[image]

1. How t build the IOS BUILD from Xcode and how to solve these issues related to ios Flutter.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

1. open terminal
2. flutter clean
3. flutter pub get
4. cd ios
5. pod install
6. flutter run

Comment: what version cocoapods i need sir?

Comment: I am using 1.11.3

Comment: Sir i am using Xcode 13 is it okay for bulidinga ios application

Comment: Have a try maybe it will work

Comment: Can you help me out in builing ISO build in FLutter Please help me

Comment: I am here for help just give a try

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246532/discussion-between-sai-mahesh-paruchuri-and-alishanmuhammadamin).

Comment: now can i build ?